# error c2373 redefinition different type modifiers with a template class

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, constants, c++03

I wrote a template `Interval` class that I would like to use as a container for an interval of numbers. Since I would like to iterate over the elements *virtually* contained in this class, I added a template `ItervalIter` friend class to the mix.

When I compile the project on Linux with `gcc` and on MacOS with `clang`, everything compiles fine without warnings. When I compile on Windows with `msvc`, I get the following error message:

```
C2373 'utils::Interval<T>::begin': redefinition. The type modifiers are different
C2447 '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
C2373 'utils::Interval<T>::end': redefinition. The type modifiers are different
C2447 '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

I have simplified my implementation of the `Interval` class so as to obtain the following [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

interval.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef INTERVAL_H_INCLUDED
#define INTERVAL_H_INCLUDED

namespace utils {

    template <class T> class IntervalIter;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Interval
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    template <class T>
    class Interval {
    public:
        Interval();
        Interval(const T value);
        virtual ~Interval();

        ///< iterator
        friend class IntervalIter<T>;
        typedef IntervalIter<T> iterator;
        typedef const IntervalIter<T> const_iterator;
        iterator begin();
        iterator end();
        const_iterator begin() const;
        const_iterator end() const;

    private:
        T value_;
    };

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// IntervalIter
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    template <class T>
    class IntervalIter {
    public:
        IntervalIter(T cur) : _cur(cur) {};

    private:
        T _cur;
    };

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Interval -- Impl.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


    template <class T>
    Interval<T>::Interval(const T value)
        : value_(value)
    {
        // nothing to do
    }

    template <class T>
    Interval<T>::~Interval()
    {
        // nothing to do
    }

    template <class T>
    typename Interval<T>::iterator Interval<T>::begin()
    {
        return this->value_;
    }

    template <class T>
    typename Interval<T>::iterator Interval<T>::end()
    {
        return this->value_;
    }

    template <class T>
    typename Interval<T>::const_iterator Interval<T>::begin() const
    {
        return const_cast<Interval<T>*>(this)->begin();
    }

    template <class T>
    typename Interval<T>::const_iterator Interval<T>::end() const
    {
        return const_cast<Interval<T>*>(this)->end();
    }


} // namespace utils
#endif
#pragma once
```

main.cpp

```
#include "interval.h"

template class utils::Interval<int>;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    utils::Interval<int> values(10);
}
```

---

The problem appears to be here:

```
    template <class T>
    typename Interval<T>::const_iterator Interval<T>::begin() const
    {
        return const_cast<Interval<T>*>(this)->begin();
    }

    template <class T>
    typename Interval<T>::const_iterator Interval<T>::end() const
    {
        return const_cast<Interval<T>*>(this)->end();
    }
```

rewriting it as follows gets rid of the error:

```
    template <class T>
    typename const IntervalIter<T> Interval<T>::begin() const
    {
        return const_cast<Interval<T>*>(this)->begin();
    }

    template <class T>
    typename const IntervalIter<T> Interval<T>::end() const
    {
        return const_cast<Interval<T>*>(this)->end();
    }
```

**Q:**

- what is going on? did I define `const_iterator` incorrectly?
- is there a better solution than the one I have found?

---

**NOTE:** I forgot to mention that I am stuck with all and only the C++ features available before `stdc++11`.

Comment: Looks very likely to be a compiler bug, however this is a moot point: your concept of what a `const_iterator` is, in the context of C++ containers, is incorrect. A `const_iterator` is not just an alias for a `const iterator`.

Comment: If `iterator` is an `object *`, a pointer to a mutable (non-const) object, a `const_iterator` is a `const object *`, a pointer to a constant object. It is not a constant pointer to a mutable object. Otherwise you can simply assign a `const_iterator` to an `iterator`, and what exactly have you accomplished? Absolutely nothing, whatsoever. You cannot assign a `const_iterator` to an `iterator`, with C++'s iterators. Yours can. It's broken by design.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for pointing out this flaw, I understand it now. With respect to solving the compilation issue, is there anything else that can be done? I am not sure that I can use `auto` because I am stuck with C++ features before `stc++11`.

Comment: If you have a conflict with a compiler bug, I'm not sure exactly what you think can be done here, short of downloading the source code to the compiler itself, figuring out the bug in its source code, and fixing it yourself. Or, of course, upgrading your compiler to a modern one. C++11 is now almost ten years old. It's time to use a modern compiler.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I agree. Unfortunately, that decision is not up to me. Thank you for your help

Comment: You can probably get away by only defining a ``const_iterator``, and then alias ``iterator`` to that for compatibility. I do not see a viable case for an application being able to modify an interval (say, extending or halving it) by accessing a *virtual* element that happens to be within range - ie.: you can not really do anything to the sequence ``[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`` by talking to ``4`` specifically. That should result in a simpler (also partially non-templated) interface and also help compatibility with C++03.